# Custom compilation flag to enable specific feature

Tags: c++, qt, makefile, qmake

I have a Qt project which requires a library (gphoto2) to enable some features that are not essential. I'd like to add some sort of configuration option to my `qmake` or `make` call to enable features using this library, so I can compile without it being installed.

What is the best way to configure something like this?
I guess I need some way to add a define based on a compiler parameter, which I can query in my code using `#ifdef ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you use `make` (without `qmake`). It is reasonable and quite easy to use [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) (alone) on Qt projects. You could use some other [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool like [ninja](http://ninja-build.org/).

Then you could decide to enable that Gphoto feature by compiling your code with `-DWITH_GPHOTO` and using `#if WITH_GPHOTO` in your C++ code.

You would compile by adding

```
CXXFLAGS+= -DWITH_GPHOTO
```

in your `Makefile`

I won't call that a "custom compiler flag" (e.g. like [GCC plugins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) can provide) but a preprocessor flag. It is pretty standard practice.

Maybe you also want to pass such flags to [moc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/moc.html). Then your `Makefile` is running `moc` thru some rule and command, which you could tailor too.

BTW, you might consider [GNU `autoconf`](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/index.html) or some other `Makefile` generator like `cmake`. I don't think you should spend too much time on these...

<sup>PS. I don't know how that idea translates into `qmake` and leave you to find out.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, you are using qmake, you can add a preprocessor definition depending on the existence of a file or an environment variable.
You could add a qmake project for compiling your external library and place it relative to your own project by default.

```
LIBGPHOTO2_PATH = $$getenv(LIBGPHOTO2PATH)
isEmpty(LIBGPHOTO2_PATH): LIBGPHOTO2_PATH = ../../libgphoto2

exists($$LIBGPHOTO2_PATH/libgphoto2.pri): include($$LIBGPHOTO2_PATH/libgphoto2.pri)
```

In libgphoto2.pri you add a preprocessor definition to indicate the presence of libgphoto2, add include and linker paths etc.:

```
DEFINES += WITH_LIBGPHOTO2
```

In the code of your dependent project, you check for the presence using `#ifdef`.

Instead of creating a qmake-project to compile, you could also check for the presence of the compiled library at a given path and set values directly (I don't know how libgphoto compiles, so I assume a default directory structure with include/, lib/ etc):

```
LIBGPHOTO2_PATH=$$getenv(LIBGPHOTO2PATH)
isEmpty(LIBGPHOTO2_PATH): LIBGPHOTO2_PATH = ../../libgphoto2

exists($$LIBGPHOTO2_PATH/include) {
    DEFINES += WITH_LIBGPHOTO2
    INCLUDEPATH += $$LIBGPHOTO2_PATH/include
    LIBS += -L$$LIBGPHOTO2_PATH/lib -lgphoto2
}
```

You should however consider to move to something more modern like `qbs`, which is a lot faster, more flexible and easier to read.